# Copy constructor called even when returning by reference?

Tags: c++

I am testing the return of local objects by reference (hopefully it is undefined behavior, to conform with my reading in Effective C++ ). My original test went well but something else happens unexpected.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class MyInt {
public:
    MyInt(int i){
        value = new int(i);
    }
    ~MyInt(){
        delete value;
    }
    int getValue(){
        return *value;
    }
    MyInt(const MyInt &b){
        cout<<"Copy"<<endl;
    }
private:
    int* value;
};

MyInt& returnref(){
    MyInt a(10);
    cout<<"Returning from returnref()"<<endl;
    return a;
}

int main(){
    MyInt a = returnref();
    cout<<a.getValue()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My console prints "Returning from ..." then "Copy" then a random value.

My understanding of pass by reference is that it does not need to make any copy. Why is it not doing what I expected?

EDIT: Don't return a reference to a local object, because it will be already destroyed outside of the function. I was just testing to see it actually happens that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MyInt a` in `MyInt a = returnref();` is not a reference, so it should be initialized. That's why copy constructor was called. And you shouldn't return a reference to a temporary object (`MyInt a(10)` is allocated on the stack and will be destroyed on exit from function), it will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: thanks, initializing "a" and then assign it to the return value works.

Comment: I intentionally wanted to see the undefined behavior.

Comment: @Johnyy "I intentionally wanted to see the undefined behavior"... you do realize that "undefined behavior" means it can do pretty much anything, right? There is no specific undefined behavior to check for.

Comment: @Johnyy: Laurence is right. The scary thing is, is that code like this will probably work correctly until you make another function call which will overwrite the stack memory that used to hold `a`

Comment: @ZanLynx ...code like that will work fine until it's running in front of a customer...  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Write this to avoid calling copy constructor:

```
 MyInt & a = returnref(); 
 //   ^^^  please note this '&'
```

But returning reference of local object is not a good idea. Read Prasoon's comment below too!

Comment: This is still dangerous. After returning from the function `a` would be destroyed so this is still UB.